# Convert Scala Serialized Code to perform Parallel Operations

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I have a scala code that take csv as an input, read each row, perform document classification of every row and stores predicted document label into MySQL database.

Problem with snippet is that, sometimes csv has 3200 rows, it takes a lot of time to completed entire operation. I need convert this code such as csv gets distributed among executors, performs document prediction and stores the label.

Following is the code snippet -

```
    val reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(args(4)))
    var readFirstLine = false;

    for (row <- reader.readAll) {
        if(readFirstLine) {
            var date = row(1).split(" ");
            var split_date = date(0).split('-').toList;
            val documentTransformed = tf.transform(row(2).split(" "))
            val emotionPredicted = model.predict(documentTransformed)
            val emotionMapped = emotionMaps(emotionPredicted);          

            //Insert Emotions               
            var query = "insert into emotions_values(user_id, year, month, day, emotion)" + "values ('"+ args(5) +"', '"+ split_date(0) +"', '"+ split_date(1) +"', '"+ split_date(2) +"', '"+ emotionMapped +"')";
            statement.executeUpdate(query)

            val polarityPredicted = polarityModel.predict(documentTransformed)
            val polarityMapped = polarityMaps(polarityPredicted);

            //Insert Polarity
            var polarityQuery = "insert into polarity_values(user_id, year, month, day, polarity)" + "values ('"+ args(5) +"', '"+ split_date(0) +"', '"+ split_date(1) +"', '"+ split_date(2) +"', '"+ polarityMapped +"')";
            statement.executeUpdate(polarityQuery)
        }
        else {
            readFirstLine = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a pretty broad question - you seem to be asking us to just write an entire Spark job for you. You might get better answers if you can narrow down to a specific Spark question that you want help with.

Comment: What I need to do for distributing my rows from csv to executors, do document labelling and inserting predicted labelled to mySQL? I am already doing document labelling and inserting data to mysql. I just need to find out how to distribute csv rows to executors?

Comment: There is a csv reader for spark: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv
I am not sure if it's outdated though.

Comment: You don't need the library as its functionality has been absorbed by Spark itself.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use the built-in CSV functionality in Spark:

```
sparkSession.read
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true") //Maybe
    .csv(args(4))
    .rdd { row =>
       ...
    }
```

This will turn the contents of your CSV into an `RDD`, which you can then manipulate as needed. Note that simply setting the `header` option to `true` ignores the first line.

I would advise looking into whether you can work with the `DataFrame` returned by the `csv` method--which will enable you to take advantage of the [Catalyst optimizations](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html) in Spark--rather than the `RDD` returned by the `rdd` method.